# Inserting Data into database from input alert dialog box

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

Its a game in which at the end activity the score is displayed But before that the input alert box is displayed where user need to add their name,and that name and score should go to the database. score is getting stored but not the name. how to get name from input alert dialog box and set it on db.insertScore(Score,Name).how am i suppose to add input value of alert dialog box to extra.getString(""); there is getter & setter method.here is my code

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extra != null)
    {
        showInputDialog();
        final String Name=extra.getString("");
        final int Score = extra.getInt("SCORE");
        final int totalQuestion = extra.getInt("TOTAL");
        int correctAnswer = extra.getInt("CORRECT");
        txtTotalScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", Score));
        txtTotalQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d/%d", correctAnswer, totalQuestion));

        progressBarResult.setMax(totalQuestion);
        progressBarResult.setProgress(correctAnswer);

        db.insertScore(Score, Name);


    }
}


protected void showInputDialog() {

    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Done.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Done.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String Name = editText.getText().toString();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: what do you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

Make the Name variable global and don't use the following line :

```
 String Name;
 Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (extra != null)
 {
    showInputDialog();
    final int Score = extra.getInt("SCORE");
    final int totalQuestion = extra.getInt("TOTAL");
    int correctAnswer = extra.getInt("CORRECT");
    txtTotalScore.setText(String.format("SCORE : %d", Score));
    txtTotalQuestion.setText(String.format("PASSED : %d/%d", correctAnswer, totalQuestion));

    progressBarResult.setMax(totalQuestion);
    progressBarResult.setProgress(correctAnswer);

    db.insertScore(Score, Name);


 }
}


protected void showInputDialog() {

// get prompts.xml view
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Done.this);
View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Done.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
// setup a dialog window
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Name = editText.getText().toString();
            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 protected void showInputDialog() {

// get prompts.xml view
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Done.this);
View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Done.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
// setup a dialog window
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                String Name = editText.getText().toString();
                //call a function which do in background and have a connection with database
             new setname(Name);
            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alert.show();
}
private void setname(final String name){
  @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params){
 Data = new HashMap<String, String>();
 Data.put("name", name);
  try {
        JSONObject json = Connection.UrlConnection("http://url", Data);
        int succ = json.getInt("success");

        if (succ == 0) {
            s = "false";
        } else {
            s = "true";
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return s;
   }
  }

}
```

Also write a php file which code insert to db

Comment: Is'nt there any simple coding?

Comment: is it confusing?